# python odd axis ticks, matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I'm currently struggeling with an odd displaying error. Seems like my ticks on the axes are only shown right, if they only consist of one number. Even when I manually set the ticks.

I'm using matplotlib. Here is an example figure:

[image]

My problem are the rectangles shown after or around the numbers.

Comment: interesting.....It looks like you have a font issue.  Have you set a non-standard font someplace?  I ask about the mac because there was a very similar issue with mac recently.  What version of mpl is this?

Comment: also is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: and can you include code that will reproduce this problem in your post?

Comment: I'm using python 2. As a matter of fact, i can't include any code because, when I try to create an example it actually works, but not in my "bigger" project. For this project I source a different Python version (My predecessor created some dependencies, which only work with another python version)

Comment: without code the reproduces the problem, there isn't much help we can provide.  Clearly _something_ is wrong, but there is no way for us to guess.

Comment: I'm still struggeling with this Problem, but nothing has changed, on my working machine, it looks like this. The same Project on another PC (still linux), has the correct axis labeling. Has no one even an idea would I should been going after?

Comment: There isn't much we can do without code to reproduce it.