# matplotlib agg ticks when rendering floating points

Tags: matplotlib, render, backend

This is the same problem as here: [python odd axis ticks, matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895980/python-odd-axis-ticks-matplotlib). Except no one is following that question so to make it little clearer:

I'm using a Linux machine:

```
$ uname -a
$ Linux stokes1 2.6.32.59-0.3-default #1 SMP 2012-04-27 11:14:44 +0200 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So this happens with Matplotlib (version 1.0.0) when using Agg (v2.2; any combination I suspect, like TkAgg etc. but I can't check for sure because only TkAgg is available on the machine). This is not my PC so I don't have root access but I can talk with the administrators and let them know about it, but I also wanted to get some details on the matter.

So basically if you take a look at the pictures you can see the problem with the ticks. Now I found out that this only happens when the ticks are floating point numbers as can be seen. I don't think it's a font problem since I'm using the standard Bitstream Vera and also this doesn't happen if I use svg as backend.

This can be reproduced by:

```
import matplotlib as m
m.use('tkagg')
from pylab import *
plot()
show()
```

[image: x, y floating point ticks]

[image: y floating point, x integer ticks]

Comment: I think the reason you got no answers is because this is a very localised problem and most likely related to your system's configuration. There is very little information for anyone to answer.

Comment: Possibly. I was thinking it might be something to do with how Agg is compiled on that system. Anyhow If I get any explanation from the administrators I'll post it here just to be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find an answer to the problem with the boxes around the floating point numbers, but the administrator of the machine gave me a workaround:

```
import matplotlib as m
m.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.1f'))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.1f'))
plt.plot()
plt.savefig('test')
```

which produces this result:
[image: workaround for floating point number boxes]

If I get an explanation from the administrator of the machine where this weird boxes appear I will add it to the answer. Meanwhile hope this helps someone.

Comment: As for your edit; you are giving the `plot` method just _one_ list, which makes the method plot the given list as y-values against the range of the length of this list. I.e. the x-values plotted are `range(len([0,2]))` which is `[0,1]`, making your plotted points `(0,0)` and `(1,2)`-> the x-limits should be from 0 to 1, not from 0 to 2. The y-limits, on the other hand, should be from 0 to 2.

Comment: You are right, thanks, I formatted the wrong axis and indeed this works. Deleted the EDIT as it's not needed anymore and accepted the answer as this is the only one...